# How to swizzle a class method on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, swizzling

Method swizzling works great for instance methods. Now, I need to swizzle a class method. Any idea how to do it?

Tried this but it doesn't work:

```
void SwizzleClassMethod(Class c, SEL orig, SEL new) {

Method origMethod = class_getClassMethod(c, orig);
Method newMethod = class_getClassMethod(c, new);

if(class_addMethod(c, orig, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod)))
    class_replaceMethod(c, new, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
else
    method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Turns out, I wasn't far away. This implementation works for me:

```
void SwizzleClassMethod(Class c, SEL orig, SEL new) {

    Method origMethod = class_getClassMethod(c, orig);
    Method newMethod = class_getClassMethod(c, new);

    c = object_getClass((id)c);

    if(class_addMethod(c, orig, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod)))
        class_replaceMethod(c, new, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
    else
        method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
}
```

Comment: Mmm ... Let's say we instead did `Class cc=object_getClass((id)c)`. It's understandable that you need to add the method to `cc`, but why did you take the class method from `cc`? Aren't you supposed to get the class method from `c` ? I'm confused ...

Comment: Yuhi, you're right, I've changed the code to do the method resolution on the original class, not the meta class. The old solution worked as well so I didn't really bother.

Comment: My bad. I mistyped object_getClass into objc_getClass. I'll delete my answer in a second.

Comment: For some reason, it does not work. Using class_getClassMethod with method_setImplementation it works, see https://newrelic.com/blog/best-practices/right-way-to-swizzle  I've tried to swizzle +[NSArray array]

Comment: @GibezynuNu Swizzling class clusters like NSArray will cause issues. Frameworks rely in a certain functionality, swizzling NSArray will break these assumptions and lead to extremely hard to reproduce bugs. Even if you could do this, please don't.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz I've just tried with a simple custom made class. Specifically, class_replaceMethod returns null.

Answer (score 2):

**Objective-C swizzling**

`Objective-C` swizzling using category

```
@interface cA : NSObject {

}
@end

@implementation cA

+(NSString*) cClassFooA {
    return @"class fooA";
}

-(NSString*) cFooA {
    return @"fooA";
}

@end


@interface cB : NSObject {

}
@end

@implementation cB

+(NSString*) cClassFooB {
    return @"class fooB";
}

-(NSString*) cFooB {
    return @"fooB";
}

@end
```

NSObject+Swizzling.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (Swizzling)

+ (void)cExchangeClassWithCls1:(Class)cls1 Sel1:(SEL)sel1 Cls2:(Class)cls2 Sel2:(SEL)sel2;
+ (void)cExchangeInstanceWithCls1:(Class)cls1 Sel1:(SEL)sel1 Cls2:(Class)cls2 Sel2:(SEL)sel2;

@end
```

NSObject+Swizzling.m

```
#import "NSObject+Swizzling.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (Swizzling)

+ (void)cExchangeClassWithCls1:(Class)cls1 Sel1:(SEL)sel1 Cls2:(Class)cls2 Sel2:(SEL)sel2 {
    
    Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls1, sel1);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls2, sel2);
    
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
}

+ (void)cExchangeInstanceWithCls1:(Class)cls1 Sel1:(SEL)sel1 Cls2:(Class)cls2 Sel2:(SEL)sel2 {
    
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls1, sel1);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls2, sel2);
    
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
}
@end
```

using via Objective-C

```
- (void)testCExchangeClass {
    [NSObject cExchangeClassWithCls1:[cA class] Sel1:@selector(cClassFooA) Cls2:[cB class] Sel2:@selector(cClassFooB)];
    
    XCTAssertEqual(@"class fooB", [cA cClassFooA]);
}

- (void)testCExchangeInstance {
    [NSObject cExchangeInstanceWithCls1:[cA class] Sel1:@selector(cFooA) Cls2:[cB class] Sel2:@selector(cFooB)];
    
    XCTAssertEqual(@"fooB", [[[cA alloc] init] cFooA]);
}
```

[[Add Swift as an consumer]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217109/4770877)

using via Swift

```
func testCExchangeClass() {
    NSObject.cExchangeClass(withCls1: sA.self, sel1: #selector(sA.sClassFooA), cls2: sB.self, sel2: #selector(sB.sClassFooB))
    
    XCTAssertEqual("class fooB", sA.sClassFooA())
}

func testCExchangeInstance() {
    NSObject.cExchangeInstance(withCls1: sA.self, sel1: #selector(sA.sFooA), cls2: sB.self, sel2: #selector(sB.sFooB))
    
    XCTAssertEqual("fooB", sA().sFooA())
}
```

[[Swift swizzling]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62412970/4770877)