# Error: CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor : 2.000000

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

```
TableViewApplication[1458:70b] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor: 2.000000
```

[image: Screenshot added]

Getting this warning while working with TableViewController. How to rectify this error and which block is affected?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: This warning also appears if image name is empty string

Answer (score 277):

This one appears when someone is trying to put `nil` in `[UIImage imageNamed:]`

Add symbolic breakpoint for `[UIImage imageNamed:]`[image: Symbolic breakpoint example]

Add `$arg3 == nil` condition on Simulator, `$r0 == nil` condition on 32-bit iPhone, or `$x2 == nil` on 64-bit iPhone.

Run your application and see where debugger will stop.

P.S. Keep in mind this also happens if image name is empty string. You can check this by adding `[(NSString*)$x2 length] == 0` to the condition.

Comment: Very nice approach! I always forget about symbolic breakpoints.

Comment: This is a clever approach. It looks like my nil image is somewhere in my nib, so it's not going through `UIImage imageNamed:`, but I'm saving this breakpoint nonetheless.

Comment: I didn't know about the `$arg3` syntax for conditional breakpoints. Where can I learn more?

Comment: Great solution, thank you. Is it possible to add condition for result, not for the argument?

Comment: Not sure to understand why it doesn't work for me, always returning ```error: use of undeclared identifier '$arg3'```. Did I miss something?

Comment: i keep getting:

Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 23.1: "$r0 == nil"
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: use of undeclared identifier '$r0'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Then what? nothing happen to tell me what asset is that!

Comment: I set condition: (int)[*(id*)($esp+12) length] == 0

Comment: $arg3 == nil (not $r0 == nil) work for me for iPhone device run

Comment: In my case the image name string was empty, so checking the arg3 length worked for me. `(int)[$arg3 length] == 0`

Comment: If you are having difficulty finding the right register create the breakpoint without the condition, then in lldb run the following `register read -f d`. Look through the printed registers to see which one contains an image name, then use that register in your breakpoint condition.

Answer (score 67):

This error (usually) happens when you try to load an image with `[UIImage imageNamed:myImage]` but iOS is not sure if `myImage` is really a `NSString` and then you have this warning.

You can fix this using:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myImage]]
```

Or you can simply check for the `length` of the name of the `UIImage`:

```
if (myImage && [myImage length]) {

    [UIImage imageNamed:myImage];
}
```

Comment: In case anyone made the same mistake I did, I was trying to update a UIButton's background image to be removed (no image at all) and so I changed my UIImage name from a string to just "", which caused the error. By removing the entire UIImage(named: "") and replacing it with nil, the error disappeared.

Comment: @DaveG You sir,  saved me hours.  Thankyou for the comment!

Answer (score 22):

Since the error is complaining that the name you gave is `(null)`, this is most likely caused by calling `[UIImage imageNamed:nil]`. Or more specifically, passing in a variable hasn't been set, so it's equal to `nil`. While using `stringWithFormat:` would get rid of the error, I think there's a good chance it's not actually doing what you want. If the name you supply is a `nil` value, then using stringWithFormat: would result in it looking for an image that is literally named "(null)", as if you were calling `[UIImage imageNamed:@"(null)"]`.

Something like this is probably a better option:

```
if (name) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

You might want to set a breakpoint in Xcode on that "Do something else" line, to help you figure out why this code is getting called with a nil value in the first place.

Comment: I got the same problem and the error was that the image name was nil like robotspacer says.

Answer (score 16):

In Xcode 6.4, this seems to occur when using "Selected Image" for a tab bar item in the storyboard, even if it's a valid image.

[image]

This doesn't actually seem to set the selected state image anyway, so it needs to be defined in User Defined Runtime Attributes, and removed from the SelectedImage attribute of the Tab Bar Item

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that! These error/warning messages were driving me nuts! I can't figure out why Apple doesn't either get rid of the Tab Bar Item "Selected Image" pulldown in IB or fix it so it works correctly.

Answer (score 5):

In my case i was passing [UIImage imageNamed:@""] which caused me to show the warning. Just add breakpoints to all the lines where you have used imageNamed and the debug the line where you find the warning.

Comment: I am also using `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` . How did you fix it?

Comment: [aButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal]

Comment: Other than using an `if` to test if the image name is not an empty string, or using a default "noImage" image, how do you display no image when no applicable name applies and the Assets do not contain a "noImage" image?

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after a storyboard was split into several (the actual change happened when I was on holidays, so I don't know exactly how it was done).

After inspecting the XML of the storyboards, I found that an image reference which previously had pointed to "bottomBar" in the assets catalogue instead pointed to `imageView:fFo-1g-jzs:image`.

At the end of the XML file under the `<resources>` tag was tag named `<image name="imageView:fFo-1g-jzs:image">` containing a big `mutableData` blob.

After resetting the image reference in the storyboard and removing the blob, the error went away.

Comment: This solved it for me, been looking for this problem for a while now, it drove me nuts. The breakpoint schtick did not work for me.

Comment: Same issue here, but the breakpoint did help me find the xib it was in. The image name was Unknown Image in IB.

Answer (score 2):

You are supplying some invalid image name, so need to validate before putting it you can do any of the above ways whichever make sense  for your code or like

```
if (iconImageName && [iconImageName length])
{

    [UIImage imageNamed:iconImageName];
}
else
{
     iconImageName.hidden = YES;
}
```

Hope it will help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have just fixed this error. Just check the usage of the `[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString*) imageName]` function. If the `imageName` is `nil`, then error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The Reason to the error is passing a nil value to the "imageNamed:" method. To avoid this, you can hide your imageView when you try to pass the nil value. The chances may occur in reusing the imageViews in UITableView or may be in scrollViews.

I avoided the warning with the below check :

```
UIImageView *your_image_view;
NSString *imageName;
if(imageName && imageName.length){
 your_image_view.hidden = NO;
 your_image_view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
else {
 your_image_view.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this warning when I load image use `[[UIImage imageNamed:normalStr] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]`, than, I change to `[UIImage imageNamed:normalStr]`, warning was gone.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is do class method swizzling to replace `[UIImage imageNamed:]` with your own implementation, then check the image name in your implementation. See the following:

[How to swizzle a class method on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267506/how-to-swizzle-a-class-method-on-ios)

I implemented this in my UIImage(Debug) category:

```
+ (UIImage *)db_imageNamed:(NSString *)imageName {
    if ([imageName length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"breakpoint here");
    }
    return [self db_imageNamed:imageName];  // not a recursive call here after swizzling
}
```

You might want to swizzle `[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have implemented cell with UILabel, UIImageView and UITextFied, sometimes I don't want to display image, in that case I'm sending empty string `""` to the imageView. Now the same error/warning is getting.

Error: `[framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: ''`

Solution is we have to pass `nil` instead of `""` empty string.

Code:

```
if imgName.count > 0 {
    selectedIconView.image = UIImage(named: imgName)
} else {
    selectedIconView.image = nil 
    //You can also use
    //selectedIconView.isHidden = true 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use this to confirm the "imageName" is not a "nil";Then you will leave away this warning.

```
 if (imageName) {
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
 }
```