# CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:

Tags: xcode, ios7, sdwebimage

In my simulator, I get the following error when a page loads: `[40438:7705280] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:`.

The images are not displaying, so the error is being thrown. However, if I refresh the view, it works. Would anyone know why this error is happening, or how I can locate the issue?

[image]

Comment: I believe that that is not the full error message, is it? Anyway, this'll probably solve it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011106/error-cuicatalog-invalid-asset-name-supplied-null-or-invalid-scale-factor

Comment: @Seth Unfortunately, that's all of it. That's why it's difficult to debug. I'll take a look at that though, thank you