# App gets crashed in main.m @autoreleasepool while scrolling uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

I am not getting any crash logs in console, i tried setting the NSZombieEnabled environmental variable to YES after that also i didn't any logs then i tried using instrument too, in that also i am not getting any logs, i am using sdwebimage to load the image using url and using cache i am retrieving, while scrolling the memory of the app gets increased.[image]

This crash is happening only in iOS 9 not in iOS 10.

i want to know which block of code is affecting my app, how to get that ?

Comment: for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011106/error-cuicatalog-invalid-asset-name-supplied-null-or-invalid-scale-factor

Comment: go on server and check image sizes... there is 1 image whose size is higher... this happened once to me because there was 1 image of 14 MB... if this is not the case, post the code on UITableView

Comment: now i fixed that issue, there is not cui catalog warning @Anbu.Karthik but still i am getting the crash.

Comment: i am having nearly 400 images, it is somewhat tuff to check all those image size and somemore points are the crash is not happening in english or tamil language script for uilabel text it is happening only for telugu language script @FahimParkar

Comment: and i checked without downloading the image also, it crashed @FahimParkar

Comment: crash is happening from heightforrow method. try to debug their

Comment: in heightforrow method i am having simply UITableViewAutomaticDimension @Aanabidden and i am having estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath too in that also i am having the same UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a Bug in Bug Reporter for the above crash issue especially for Telugu Script in iOS-9.

Got a Reply from Apple Like below

"" Apple Developer Relations

Engineering has provided the following information regarding this issue:

This is crashing in CoreText. However, if this is resolved in iOS 10, we are not able to make an update to iOS 9. Please verify and ensure its working on iOS 11.

iOS 11 beta 7 (15A5362a) https://developer.apple.com/download/

If the issue persists, please attach a new sysdiagnose captured in the latest build and attach it to the bug report.

iOS sysdiagnose Instructions: https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/iOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf

For a complete list of logging instructions visit: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/ ""