# Is there any way to use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` in appdelegate for all UIImage Property across the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor myColor]];
[[UITextView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor myColor]];
```

After setting `UITextField` & `UITextView` cursor color in appDelegate, suddenly I am facing that there is a lot of `NavigationItemBar` image turn into default Blue color. It's actual color is not showing. The solution is to set each `NavigationItemBar` image rapped up with this, `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`

Like:

```
`[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`
```

I am just wondering is there any way to set this `UIImage` property (`UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`) in `appDelegate`? So that I don't have to change every place in my project, rather set in one place.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is any such a way exist :(

Comment: Messy solution I used but it works. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267506/how-to-swizzle-a-class-method-on-ios) and my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the obj-c runtime.

```
<objc/runtime.h>
```

Declare the following C function to swizzle a method.

```
void SwizzleClassMethod(Class c, SEL orig, SEL new) {

    Method origMethod = class_getClassMethod(c, orig);
    Method newMethod = class_getClassMethod(c, new);

    c = object_getClass((id)c);

    if(class_addMethod(c, orig, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod)))
        class_replaceMethod(c, new, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
    else
        method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
}
```

Declare a new method to swizzle into a category of `UIImage`

```
+ (instancetype)renderingMode_imageNamed:(NSString *)imageName {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage renderingMode_imageNamed:imageName];
    return [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
```

Override `+load` in the `UIImage` category

```
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        SwizzleClassMethod([UIImage class], @selector(imageNamed:), @selector(renderingMode_imageNamed:))
    })
}
```

Import your category.

Now every time you use `+imageNamed`, it will change the rendering mode automatically.

Comment: Phew, that took a long while to type.

Comment: Many many thanks for your answer. Actually I already start my change manually in every place. But your answer looks like perfect to me. And you also refer the link. Which is awesome. Thanks man for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the custom `UIBarButtonItem` and try.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Sample title"];
    UIImageView *customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    [customView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SettingIcon"]];
    UIBarButtonItem *right = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:right];
}

@end
```

This is working for me.

Comment: He wants a way to set it globally, not individually.